# sql clr c# function to make rest api call

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL CLR C# function/store procedure to get data from an api server but I'm not getting proper results. Probably I never wrote and never done this. I have searched a lot and found the following code, but this returns data in a full page format where as I want only data in xml format so that I can process it in SQL Server. Also I am passing an url and username password which is Ok, how can I add more parameters to this?

//code

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
usig System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;

// For the SQL Server integration
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

// Other things we need for WebRequest
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public partial class Functions
{
    // Function to return a web URL as a string value.
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static SqlString GET(SqlString uri, SqlString username, SqlString passwd)
    {
        // The SqlPipe is how we send data back to the caller
        SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
        SqlString document;

        // Set up the request, including authentication
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Convert.ToString(uri));

        if (Convert.ToString(username) != null & Convert.ToString(username) != "")
        {
             req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Convert.ToString(username), Convert.ToString(passwd));
        }

        ((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = "CLR web client on SQL Server";

        // Fire off the request and retrieve the response.
        // We'll put the response in the string variable "document".
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

        Stream dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        document = (SqlString)rdr.ReadToEnd()

        // Close up everything...
        rdr.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        resp.Close();

        // .. and return the output to the caller.
        return (document);
    }
}
```

This code returns this result:

```
<html>        <head><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="/api.asmx?disco" />        <style type="text/css">          BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; }    #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; }    A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }    A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }    A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }    A:hover { color: cc3300; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }    P { color: #000000; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 12px; font-family: Verdana; }    pre { background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; font-size: x-small; margin-top: -5px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; }    td { color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; }    h2 { font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #003366; margin-left: -15px; color: #003366; }    h3 { font-size: 1.1em; color: #000000; margin-left: -15px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }    ul { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }    ol { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }    li { margin-top: 10px; color: #000000; }    font.value { color: darkblue; font: bold; }    font.key { color: darkgreen; font: bold; }    font.error { color: darkred; font: bold; }    .heading1 { color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal; background-color: #003366; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: -30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 15px; width: 105%; }    .button { background-color: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; border-top: #cccccc 1px solid; border-bottom: #666666 1px solid; border-left: #cccccc 1px solid; border-right: #666666 1px solid; }    .frmheader { color: #000000; background: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; font-weight: normal; border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; }    .frmtext { font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 32px; }    .frmInput { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; }    .intro { margin-left: -15px; }                   </style>        <title>   API Web Service  </title></head>      <body>        <div id="content">          <p class="heading1">API</p><br>                              <span>            <p class="intro">Click <a href="api.asmx">here</a> for a complete list of operations.</p>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "full page format". Please show what you get back (at least partial if it is large) and what you expect or want to get back.

Comment: First design the xml structure with tags.  The parameters will be the tags of the xml string.

Comment: Just Edited the current question what i am getting back.. I am not good with c# can you please let me show me how to structure xml and tags